# Is English the official language for international sport events?

Tags: olympics, tournaments, international-sports, terminology

There are specific languages official for every sports (i.e. soccer/cricketboxing) / sport events (olympics/world events/continental events)?

I think the mostly used is English, but what about for example South American Games? And other international events?

Is there a rule in this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no general rule. It depends on the sport and the event. For example, the official language of the [Lusophony Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusophony_Games) is (unsurprisingly!) Portuguese.

Answer (score 6):

It depends of the event. For the Olympics, there are two official languages : English and French (which is by its reglementation the most important language of the Olympics). For FIFA, these languages are English, French, but also German and Spanish.

Comment: It varies a bit by sport (athletics, like the Olympics, operates in English and French). The Olympics do have a third "official" language, which is the language of the host nation.